# how can i upload a file in google cloud storage without using GAE

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud storage bucket and I was trying to upload some simple text files to it. I checked the online documentation on google and it mainly showed to do this using Google App Engine. But I found it to be a bit difficult. Is there any other simpler method to upload simple files to google cloud storage without creating a google app engine. Links and codes are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics) which lists the options available for uploading objects to storage.

I recommend [GSUtil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) which is Google's command line program from interfacing with Google Cloud Storage.  You will need to download and install the program on your computer to use it but it's relatively painless.

Once installed, you can use commands to transfer files such as:

```
gsutil cp gs://storage-bucket-of-doom/* <my local path>
```

GSUtil also supports multi-threading to speed up downloads, which the API Client Libraries may not.

I hope this helps!

Paul